# Dynamically binding NavigationViewItem && NavigationViewItemHeader in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, uwp

I want to populate `NavigationViewItem`s and `NavigationViewItemHeader`s dynamically in my `NavigationView`. However, I can not make it work. It looks like my `ListView`only take the space of one item. How can I create new Items dynamically?

MainMenu.xaml

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavViewTester"
                ItemInvoked="NavViewTester_ItemInvoked"Loaded="NavViewTester_Loaded" 
                IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="True" IsPaneOpen="True">
     <NavigationView.MenuItems>
         <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="My Books">
         </NavigationViewItemHeader>
     </NavigationViewItemHeader>  

         <Grid x:Name="BooksGrid">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="320" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ListView
                x:Name="NavigationListView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationListViewItemTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind books.getBooks()}" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="NavigationListView_ItemClick"
                >
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>

        </Grid>   
     </NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

I also tried `NavigationViewList` instead of my `ListView` but it is not helping.

Comment: How did you define the `books` and `getBooks()` method and `NavigationListViewItemTemplate`? Please provide your c# code, otherwise, I could not help you more.

Answer (score 3):

> But I also have a MenuItemHeader which disappears after using your
>   solution

To get both `NavigationViewItem` and `NavigationViewItemHeader` dynamically from list. You need to set the `IEnumerable` type to their base class **`NavigationViewItemBase`**. It Worked fine for me

```
<NavigationView  MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Items,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

//C# Code

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
        public  IEnumerable<NavigationViewItemBase> Items { get; set; }
        private readonly NavigationViewItem Item1 = new NavigationViewItem() { Icon = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uEC06" }, Content = "Item1" };
        private readonly NavigationViewItem Item2 = new NavigationViewItem() { Icon = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uE13C" }, Content = "Item2" };
        private readonly NavigationViewItemHeader Header1 = new NavigationViewItemHeader() { Content = "Header1" };
        private readonly NavigationViewItem Item3 = new NavigationViewItem() { Icon = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uEC06" }, Content = "Item3" };
        private readonly NavigationViewItem Item4 = new NavigationViewItem() { Icon = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uE13C" }, Content = "Item4" };
        private readonly NavigationViewItemHeader Header2 = new NavigationViewItemHeader() { Content = "Header2" };
        public MainPage()
        {
            Items = GetItems();
            this.InitializeComponent();            
        }
        private IEnumerable<NavigationViewItemBase> GetItems()
        {
            yield return Header1;
            yield return Item1;
            yield return Item2;
            yield return Header2;
            yield return Item3;
            yield return Item4;
        }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out `MenuItemsSource` dependency property, that its defined on the `NavigationView` class.

### MainPage.cs :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        myItems = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
    }

    List<string> myItems { get; set; }
}
```

### MainPage.xaml:

```
<NavigationView
    x:Name="NavView"
    MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind myItems}">
</NavigationView>
```

For the sake of simplicity, performed binding with `x:Bind`, and using the default `OneTime` mode seems appropriate.

[image]

Comment: I guess it is not what I'm looking for since I set the Source for all MenuItems. But I also have a MenuItemHeader which disappears after using your solution